# Preventing other threads from running a piece of code

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to prevent to other threads(illegal threads) from running `run()`. the solution is:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        if (currentThread() != this)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Exception occurred by: " + currentThread().toString());

        /* Here goes the main logic of thread */ 
    }
}
```

How could we do the same thing when `MyThread` class is directly implementing `Runnable`?

Comment: Sounds like you should rethink your design instead.

Comment: Why would any piece of code in your program be calling the run() method on a Thread in the first place?

Comment: @craig: It would not:D. I'm only learning how to do it in different ways.

Comment: Learning how to do what, exactly? I think if you update your question with a quick outline of what you're trying to accomplish, we'll be able to guide you in the right direction. :) The run() method for a Thread should (in theory) only be executed by the Thread object in which the method resides. If you create two instances of MyThread, they should each execute inside their own run() methods. If you're running this from the command-line, you'll have 3 threads of execution: Main:someMethod(), MyThread-1:run(), and MyThread-2:run().

Comment: This sounds like you are trying stop myself from doing the wrong thing. It remind me of the quote "If Your Right Hand Offend You, Cut it Off" to which the smart reply is; "And if my left hand offers me how do I cut it off?" - My answer is; you should write the code correctly in the first place, and don't get into such arguments with yourself. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply store a reference to the `Thread` that is allowed to run the code as a member in your `Runnable` class. Use that in the comparison.

Comment: I mean I want to allow all `MyThread` instances but deny others.

Comment: If MyThread is just a Runnable, and not a Thread, that does not make sense (Runnables are run by threads, they don't run themselves).

Comment: While what you're trying to accomplish isn't really good practice, it sounds like you could use: **if (!(currentThread() instanceof MyThread)) {return;}**